# Response pattern matching in apache jmeter

Tags: regex, json, jmeter

I am trying to do a response pattern match in Apache Jmeter.

Here is a pattern that I have:

```
\{"exactMatchedResourceGroups" : \[ \{* "group2" * \} \],"parentMatchedResourceGroups" : \[ \]\}
```

I am trying to match this pattern with the below response:

```
{
 "exactMatchedResourceGroups" : [ {
 "id" : "b2f7947e-f502-4ad7-88b1-f7ac41bd44a7",
 "name" : "group2",
 "tags" : [ "" ]
} ],
"parentMatchedResourceGroups" : [ ]
}
```

I am getting this response from the server, but still the test is failing. So, I am guessing its a problem with my regex. I can't seem to figure out where the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
\{\s*"exactMatchedResourceGroups"\s*:\s*\[\s*\{.*?"group2".*?\s*\}\s*\]\s*,\s*"parentMatchedResourceGroups"\s*:\s*\[\s*\]\s*\}
```

you need to use option "s" dot all mode